# Throwing an http code error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to pass an error code in JavaScript:

```
try{ /*do something*/ }
catch { /*throw a 404 error*/ }
```

Comment: You mean from Node.js or some other server-side environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** "throw" a 404 error with client side javascript.

You *can* just replace the page with new content, or change the location of the page to a page that does not exist